# Xamarin Forms : Android App can run in debug mode but crashed in release mode when changing language

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I work on android app in xamarin cross platform. I have problem when the application run in release mode with datepicker. If I have datepicker in view ,I can run application normally in debug mode. If I build release .apk file and install to device, the application will crash in case of setting language&input on device as Thai language (the other language e.g. English,France can run normally). I'm not sure the problem is about the B.E. format or not and how can I fix this problem thank you.

Comment: Are you sure the Thai language is installed on the device ?

Comment: Yes, when I run in debug mode it can run normally with thai language setting on device but not in release mode

Comment: have you got the folder values and values-thai (I don't know the exact syntaxe) for your string.xml files ?

Comment: Add some code in your question if you do some king of stuff when changing language

Comment: sorry, I can not find string.xml in my xamarin project

Comment: it's in the Droid project, in the Resources folder, and the Values folder and there is the Strings.xml

Comment: <DatePicker VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Date="{x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}">
                <DatePicker.Format>yyyy-MM-dd</DatePicker.Format>
</DatePicker>  
I add tag above below Label tag in MainPage.xaml in simple xamarin cross platform project using visual studio

Comment: do you mean styles.xaml ?

Comment: no strings.xml, it's a Xamarin Forms or Xamarin.Android project ?

Comment: It's a Xamarin Forms project like I see in the code

Comment: sorry I think It's a Xamarin Forms project

Comment: I suppose it's because the date Format change when using Thai language, you must handle this case

Comment: sorry for wrong tag. I edit to xamarin.forms

Comment: It's an error like this one I suppose : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26315275/app-crashes-when-the-user-changes-the-device-language

Comment: the  sys:DateTime.Now will not correspond to the date format I suppose

Comment: Can I set default datetime as string value in xaml file.

Comment: Yes use Binding or code in the .xaml.cs file associated to your MainPage.xaml

Comment: I will try your suggestion and will reply later. thank you so much

Comment: Ok no problem see you later

Comment: <DatePicker x:Name="MyDatePicker" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Date="{x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}"> 
        </DatePicker>

Comment: In your code behind :  MyDatePicker.Format = "yyyy-MM-dd";

Comment: You can also set the Date by using MyDatePicker.Date and remove the {x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that when you change the language in the device, the system Date Format does not correspond to the DateTime Format.

Try to set it in code when changing the language :

In xaml :

```
   <DatePicker x:Name="MyDatePicker" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                 Date="{x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}">
       </DatePicker>
```

In C# :

```
 MyDatePicker.Format = "yyyy-MM-dd"; 
 MyDatePicker.Date = new DateTime(); // Set the date time as you want it. And remove the Date attribute in the Xml
```

Hope it helps

Comment: The problem still occur. I'm not sure where to put c# code , because now I put it in initializeComponent after find that component in xaml file. Maybe datepicker component has been created before execute c# code and make error occur again. Does It has Event like beforeCreate Method that I can put your code before?

Comment: the C# code must be add after InitializeComponent(); in the constructor. You can try to use the override void OnAppearing() in the same class. You can edit your question and add code it can be more easily to find the error

Comment: update now app can run. I add cultureInfo to threadCurrent in onStart() and onResume() method in MainActivity.cs

Comment: Ok cool ! Edit my answer or create yours and validate it, that can help other people