# How to prevent a fragment (e.g. Alert Dialogfrom) from being destroyed in device languege change or in resume state?

Tags: android, android-fragments, error-handling, android-alertdialog

My app crashed when I changed the device language with two parts error in `logcat`. Similar Post: [App crashes when the user changes the device language](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26315275/22635266) and [My app crashes when my phone's language is set to Persian or Arabic because of Double.parseDouble](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35872491/22635266)

```
android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.myapp.MainActivity has leaked window DecorView@f97fb0a[MainActivity] 
that was originally added here
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:733)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:717)
at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:399)
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:109)
at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:340)
at com.myapp.dialog.showDialog(DialogCenter.java:190)
at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:3147)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:588)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:272)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1943)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1845)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1782)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$5.run(FragmentManager.java:565)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

```
Shutting down VM
com.myappFATAL EXCEPTION: main
com.myappProcess: com.myapp, PID: 8843
com.myappjava.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myapp/com.myapp.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #59 in com.myapp:layout/main_activity: Binary XML file line #59 in com.myapp:layout/main_activity: Error inflating class fragment
com.myappat android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
com.myappat android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
com.myappat android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:5456)
com.myappat android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:5362)
com.myappat android.app.servertransaction.ActivityRelaunchItem.execute(ActivityRelaunchItem.java:69)
com.myappat android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
com.myappat android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
com.myappat android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
com.myappat android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
com.myappat android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
com.myappat android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
com.myappat java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
com.myappat com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
com.myappat com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
com.myappCaused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #59 in com.myapp:layout/main_activity: Binary XML file line #59 in com.myapp:layout/main_activity: Error inflating class fragment
com.myappCaused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #59 in com.myapp:layout/main_activity: Error inflating class fragment
com.myappCaused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton.setBackgroundTintList(android.content.res.ColorStateList)' on a null object reference
com.myappat com.myapp.LocationFragment.onViewCreated(LocationSelectionFragment.java:143)
com.myappat androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:3147)
com.myappat androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:588)
com.myappat androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:272)
com.myappat androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:114)
com.myappat androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1455)
com.myappat androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3034)
com.myappat androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchViewCreated(FragmentManager.java:2945)
com.myappat androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:3148)
com.myappat androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.ensureInflatedView(FragmentStateManager.java:410)
com.myappat androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:271)
com.myappat androidx.fragment.app.FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.onCreateView(FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.java:142)
com.myappat androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:136)
com.myappat androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:247)
com.myappat androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:226)
com.myappat android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1067)
com.myappat android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:995)
com.myappat android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:959)
com.myappat android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1121)
com.myappat android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
com.myappat android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1124)
com.myappat android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
com.myappat android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:680)
com.myappat android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:532)
com.myappat android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479)
com.myappat androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:775)
com.myappat androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:197)
com.myappat com.myapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:115)
com.myappat android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7994)
com.myappat android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7978)
com.myappat android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
com.myappat android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
com.myappat android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
com.myappat android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:5456)
com.myappat android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:5362)
com.myappat android.app.servertransaction.ActivityRelaunchItem.execute(ActivityRelaunchItem.java:69)
com.myappat android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
com.myappat android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
com.myappat android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
com.myappat android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
com.myappat android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
com.myappat android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
com.myappat java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
com.myappat com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
com.myappat com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
AppsFilter              system_process                       I  interaction: PackageSetting{46efb40 com.myapp/10154} -> PackageSetting{74eaa79 com.android.vending/10099} BLOCKED
ActivityTaskManager     system_process                       W  Force finishing activity com.myapp/.MainActivity
Process                 com.myapp                            I  Sending signal.
WIN DEATH: Window{bff4098 u0 com.myapp/com.myapp.MainActivity}
```

I've tried this TEST in two other apps.

- In telegram app, when I open a page that contains an alert dialog, and I pause the app then change the device language but coming back to the app it closes the alert dialog. Telegram close any popped up dialogs in any pause state.
- I tested this behavior in another app. In that app the dialog keeps open in a simple pause state but when I pause the app and change the device language and come back to the app the dialog disappear.
- I tested this behavior for "Android Permission dialog". Surprisingly it remains open without any app crash or error.

> **QUESTION:** How to fix this issue?

I think I should do something in `onPause()` and `onResume()` methods. (note that I have many Alert dialog in the fragment.)

> Can one achieve the robust behavior of "Android Permission dialog"?

I think one candidate for reason of the above issue is the following:

> **MAIN QUESTION:** In all of my fragments, the resume mode triggers some action in the fragment. Reopening the Alert Dialog, triggering the swipe Refresh layout, pressing some buttons etc. Why this happening and how to prevent this bad behavior?